# Use the adjacency list to find the full path traversal

Tags: java, graph

I am doing an exercise. I am supposed to find the full path traversal from 0 to 6? This is an example of a DIGraph. 0-6 are the nodes and the numbers to the right are the relationships connected to them. Thank you for your time. Here is the adjacency list:

```
0   0,1,5
1   1,0
2   2,3,4
3   1,2
4   0,2,3,6
5   0,3
6   1,0
```

I came up with this path but i am not sure if it is correct.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about graph theory and not a programming problem, post some code that you need help with if you have it.

Comment: Well, you are missing 6. What algorithm are you using? Also, 1 and 2 are not connected according to your adjacency list, but in your answer you have them connected.

Answer (score 2):

Your completed graph should contain all adjacencies listed in the given adjacency list. Here is what a path traversal from 0 to 6 should look like given that you need to traverse as many nodes as possible:

```
0 - 5 - 3 - 2 - 4 - 6
```

another option is:

```
0 - 1 - 3 - 2 - 4 - 6
```

Note that either `1` or `5` is inaccessible as it exists within a cycle between `0, 5, 3, 1`.